# Docusign not displaying tabLabels but names instead

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony, docusignapi

I'm using Docusign's REST API for creating template and sending it to the customer to sign it - everything works fine but the template doesn't display the labels of the tabs (textTabs), there are their names showed only
I'm sending everything in an evelope, an item looks like this:

```
"textTabs": [
        {
          "anchorString": "app_contractbundle_contract_masterAgreement_salesforceId",
          "anchorUnits": "pixels",
          "anchorXOffset": 105,
          "anchorYOffset": -3,
          "documentId": 1,
          "name": "masterAgreement_salesforceId",   - this is displayed in the template
          "pageNumber": null,
          "xPosition": 0,
          "yPosition": 0,
          "tabLabel": "Salesforce ID",   - this should be displayed
          "value": null,
          "fontSize": null,
          "locked": true,
          "required": true
        },
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not documented well in the API docs but the `name` property is what's used for the help tip on tabs, not the `tabLabel`.  Either switch your values or just set the `name` to the same thing as your `tabLabel`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The problem is that I use the name fields to identify the tabs when they come back from Docusign as a push message and then I extract the updated values.. The values for tabLabels don't get sent back.. Is there any other way to identify them? I guess the only chance to do that is to use their index..

Comment: You can make the **Get Tab Information for a Recipient** API call to retrieve the `tabLabel` values